# Unable to join data from another layer

Tags: polygon, fields-attributes, spatial-join, boundaries, within

I have two polygon layers, I want to join the data based on the location from one layer to another layer. But only field is joining not the data.

[image]

In image green is one layer and red is another layer. What kind of join i have to use intersection or contains or within or overlap to get the data from the boundary red to green boundaries.

In what cases the data may not join if data contains any issues

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the attribute table from one layer to another, "join attributes by location" function with "intersect" geometric predicate, should work.
If each feature has it's distinct value on attribute table, "Join Attributes by location" with "intersect" might not work due to the fact that the shapes are not identic and the values can be joined from multiple features that get intersected. In this case you can select "overlaps" geometric predicate, so each feature can get it's value only from features that are overlapped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join attribute data of one layer to other then you should use "Joins and Relates". Run the join command with "Join data from another layer based on spatial location".
OR
You can join attribute data by using "Spatial Join" setting different environment according to your need.